# Python elemento IN lista de strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo la siguiente lista y string:

```
lis = ['ejemplo 1', 'ejemplo 2', 'cualquier cosa']
palabra = 'ejemplo'
```

Pero cuando hago

```
palabra in lis
```

Me retorna `False`. ¿A qué se debe? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque estas buscando en la lista y la cadena `'ejemplo'` no está en la lista como tal. Tal y como lo tienes se compara tu string `palabra` por cada elemento de la lista.

Lo que quieres es ver si la **subcadena** `palabra` está dentro de las cadenas contenidas en la lista. Para ello debes buscarla dentro de cada elemento de la lista. Puedes usar `any` para ello:

```
>>> lis = ['ejemplo 1', 'ejemplo 2', 'cualquier cosa']
>>> palabra = 'ejemplo'
>>> any(palabra in string for string in lis)
```

Puedes seguir la misma lógica para hacer otras cosas:

Si queres  saber el número de veces que aparece puedes usar :

```
>>> sum(palabra in string for string in lis)
```

Si deseas ver que cadenas son y el indice que ocupan en la lista puedes usar `enumerate()`:

```
lis = ['ejempl2o 1', 'ejempl2o 2', 'cualquier cosa']
palabra = 'ejemplo'
res = [(indice, string)for indice, string in enumerate(lis) if palabra in string]
print(res)
```

Nos retorna:

```
>>> [(0, 'ejemplo 1'), (1, 'ejemplo 2')]
```